# Ubuntu Server, Erro loop de Script, Abrir en una terminal y ejecutar

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, bash, script

Chicos, me ayudan, realice un script que ejecuta los comandos donde esta el entorno virtual y Python, funciona bien, logre hacerlo funcionar al inicio del sistema, sin usar crontab, lo cual con netstat -ntlp reviso que se este ejecutando y no hay problema, pero NO logro ver la consola donde se esta ejecutando Python, trate con de que el script se ejecutara abriendo una consola al inicio del sistema, con:

```
gnome-terminal -e "./server_script.sh"
```

Pero me hace un loop, alguien me puede ayudar,

```
#!/bin/bash

#Ejecutar en Terminal "Esto puede cambiar según la ruta del Script"
cd /home/admin-server/
./server_script.sh

#Colores
redColor="\e[0;31m\033[1m"
greenColor="\e[0;32m\033[1m"
endColor="\033[0m\e[0m"
yellowColor="\e[0;33m\033[1m"



echo -e "\n"
echo -e "${greenColor}***** ******************************** *******${endColor}"
echo -e "*****${yellowColor} Bienvenido Al Server Script v1.0${endColor} *******"
echo -e "${greenColor}***** ******************************** *******\n${endColor}"
echo -e "*** ${yellowColor} Verificando Procesos Activo Con El Puerto ${redColor}8000${endColor}, Espere...${endColor} ***\n"
sleep 2
echo -e "${greenColor}Verificando...\n${endColor}"
netstat -ntlp
echo -e "Matando Proceso Python\n"
kill -9 2740
echo -e "Listo\n"
netstat -ntlp
echo -e "${greenColor}***** ******************************** *******\n${endColor}"
echo " "
echo -e "**** ${yellowColor} Activando Entorno Virtual, Por Favor Espere...${endColor} ****"
echo " "
sleep 3
echo " "

#Comando para dirigirnos a la  ruta donde se encuentra nuestro entorno virtual "Esto podría cambiar según su Ubicación"
cd /home/admin-server/control_flota/venvp1/bin/

#Posterior Ejecutar con el siguiente Comando.
source activate



echo -e "**** ${greenColor} Entorno Virtual Activado Correctamente :)${endColor} ****"
echo " "
pwd
echo " "
echo -e "*** ${yellowColor} Ejecutando el siguiente comando:  python3 manage.py runserver${endColor}\n"
sleep 3
echo -e "${greenColor}Por Favor Espere...${endColor}\n"
sleep 1
echo -e "**** ${greenColor} Comando Ejecutado Con Exito... :)${endColor} ******\n"
echo " "
echo -e "${redColor} Nota:"
echo -e " - Si el servidor se Reinicia o Apaga, se Ejecutara Automáticamente al Iniciar el Sistema."
echo -e " - Cada Noche a las ${endColor} ${greenColor} 23:59 ${endColor} ${redColor}, Se hará un Reinicio Automático del Servidor.${endColor}"
echo " "
#Comando para ejecutar runserver de python3, en la ruta especifica.
cd /home/admin-server/control_flota/sistema_gestion_flota/
python3 manage.py runserver


Terminal=true
```

Ejecuto la Distro Ubuntu Server 20.4

Answer (score 0):

Bien, logre solucionar después de amanecerme, encontré una solución.

Primero el Script para ejecutarlo al inicio del sistema Gnome, se ocupa un Script Padre que ejecute en consola los Script Hijos Asi:

Script Padre

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " "
echo "Ejecutando Script Server v1.0"
echo " "
sleep 2
echo " "
x-terminal-emulator -e /home/admin-server/server_script.sh
x-terminal-emulator -e /home/admin-server/reiniciar.sh
```

Si se fijan x-terminal-emulator, hace que el script se ejecute en una terminal aparte si ejecutamos en la consola ./Script.sh.

Entonces el primer Script "server_script.sh", ejecuta los comandos para activar el entorno virtual y ejecutar python3 manage.py runserver.

El segundo Script ejecuta un reinicio del sistema cada x cantidad de hora.

Ahora como ejecutarlo al inicio del sistema, en el menu colocar startup aplication y basta en darle al Add y agregar la ruta del script Padre para ejecutarlo y esta.

PD: Ojo con las ruta del script Padre y los permisos de ejecución "chmod +x Script.sh"

Funciona... :)